# Mahalanobis distance

Tags: matlab, statistics

I would like to apply Mahalanobis distanc method to the data obained from the observation.
Each observation is a time response of the system. I have 30 onservations each 14000 points.
I would like to use MAHAL command in matlab. but it notifies me that the number of the rows in variable X must be greater than the columns. But the nature of my observations is so that for each observation I have 1 row (observation) and 14000 columns (time points).
I don't know how to overcome such a problem.
If anybody knows please help me.

Comment: I think you can solve the problem by transposing your observation matrix. The reason is the function tries to find a mean and a sigma for each input vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The Mahalanobis distance of a point `x` from a group of values with mean `mu` and variance `sigma` is defined as `sqrt((x-mu)*sigma^-1*(x-mu))`. If `sigma` is not invertible - and it will not be if you have 30 observations and 14000 variables - the Mahalanobis distance is not defined.